# How to use setFieldValue and pass the value as props between components

Tags: forms, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to use ant design forms in my sample registration form, when i'm trying to use setFieldsValue it throws error as "Cannot use setFieldsValue unless getFieldDecorator is used". But I had already used getFieldDecorator in my code.Here is a sample of my code.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  const fname = e.target.name;
  const fvalue = e.target.value;
  this.props.setFieldsValue({
    fname: fvalue
  });
}
render(){
  const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form
  return (
    <Row gutter={4}>
      <Col className="reg-personal-details-grid-column" span={24}>
        <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="First Name">
          {getFieldDecorator("firstName", {
            rules: [
              {
                required: true
              }
            ]
          })(
            <Input
              placeholder="First Name"
              required
              name="firstName"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            )}
        </FormItem>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  )
}
```

Comment: why using const for a varible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`fname` is not defined in `getFieldDecorator`.

You should do this:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  const fname = e.target.name;
  const fvalue = e.target.value;
  this.props.form.setFieldsValue({
    [fname]: fvalue
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks you... Was my mistake in declaring the fname where the setFields function took it as a string?

Comment: @Shibu yes when you refer variable name inside setFieldsValue it takes as string and that created your problem

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own function to do this:

```
export const setFieldValue = (
    form: FormInstance,
    name: NamePath,
    value: string
): void => {
    if (form && form.getFieldValue(name)) {
        const fixname: string[] = [];
        if (typeof name == 'object') {
            name.forEach((node: string) => {
                fixname.push(node);
            });
        } else {
            fixname.push(String(name));
        }
        let fieldsValue: unknown;
        fixname.reverse().forEach((node: string) => {
            fieldsValue = {
                [String(node)]: fieldsValue != undefined ? fieldsValue : value,
            };
        });
        form.setFieldsValue(fieldsValue);
    }
};
```

and you can use like that

```
setFieldValue(form, 'phone', '1111111111');
```

or

```
setFieldValue(form, ['phones', 'mobile'], '2222222222');
```

Answer (score 3):

In Antd v4, you only required to call the **setFieldsValue** in **useEffect** function.

```
    const [form] = Form.useForm()
    
     useEffect(() => {
      //companyInfo -> dynamic obj fetched from API
     form.setFieldsValue(companyInfo);
     }, [companyInfo, form]);
```

Then in ***Form*** use the ***form*** prop as follow:

```
     <Form
     //passing form prop 
      form={form}
      labelCol={{ span: 8 }}
      wrapperCol={{ span: 14 }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      labelAlign="left"
      colon={false}
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this

```
const formRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
 formRef.current?.setFieldsValue({
  name: data?.firstName,
 });
}, [data]);

return (
  <Form ref={formRef}>
    <Form.Item name="name">
      <Input/>
    </Form.Item>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].